# How to add Conditional Formatting in Excel for a Range of Values

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, highlight

I have an excel spreadsheet set up like a report card.  The values are given as percentages.  I'm looking to highlight all values between 0-49 in one color, 50-99 in another, and those equal to 100 in a third color.  I'm having trouble applying these 3 different conditions in the range when I create a new rule.  It keeps assuming I am wanting to score the numbers as a percentage of each other rather than just the actual number in the cell if that makes sense.  Any help is appreciated!

[image: Current Results]

Comment: Can you show us what you have done? It will be easier to fix the problem instead of going through every step, most of which you are probably already familiar with

Comment: You can use Conditional formatting.

Comment: Conditional formatting. Cell value between and make your criteria as necessary.

Comment: I just updated original post with pictures of what is happening.  I've played with the formulas quite a bit and while I'm getting closer it still won't work.  I don't want a gradient scale.  I just want all values under 50% to be red, all values 50%-99% to be yellow and all values of 100% to be green if that helps make the problem clear.  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I tried to add pics of my formula, but unfortunately being new it looks like it isn't working and I can't add another picture.

Comment: As a new user your pictures must be approved. I've done that and they are showing now.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you Teylyn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three separate rules, one for each condition. Select the range and create new rules that uses a formula. You can see the formulas I used in this example. Note that the formula must reference the first cell in the selection and should not contain $ signs, i.e. use `C2` and not `$c$2`. In my example, C2 is the first cell in the selection and my rules are

```
=C2<0.5
=C2<1
=C2=1
```

Look at the screenshot and see how the rules must be ordered so the yellow is not applied to cells under 50%. You could also use the tick box for "Stop if true" to make sure no further rules are applied.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to answer my question.  I don't have anything that says "Rules Manager.  My choices under conditional formatting includes "New Rules" "Clear Rules" and "Manage Rules".  When I go to Manage it gives me the option to Edit, but does not look like what you have here.  I'm using Excel version 16.56 if that matters.  I do have a Stop if True box but it doesn't actually allow me to click it.   It also states for each choice just "Graded Color Scale" , "Format" and "Applies to" but doesn't allow me to change anything but the range (won't get rid of the gradient colors either).

Comment: What operating system/hardware are you using Excel on? If it's Excel for Windows, use Home Ribbon > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.  Then use the formulas I mention. If you already have a rule from one of the easy pick and choose options, you won't be able to change that to a formula rule. You need to delete that rule and start over.

Comment: Thank you SO much!  This is actually very helpful.  I am using a mac and it didn't occur to me that is why it wasn't working.  When I logged on a PC, I can see things that weren't available there, and can see the options you have provided, so I'm sure I can get this working now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, Excel for Mac is very different from Excel for Windows, so you may want to mention you're using a Mac when you are asking Excel questions.

Comment: Will do so in the future!  Thanks again for your help.  As soon as I moved to a PC I was able to easily accomplish the task following your instructions!